# How to handle Extent Reports' createtest() method in Cucumber-Java-TestNG framework?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, cucumber-java, extentreports

I am looking for implementation help for logging in extent report. I want my feature names to be logged only once in the report and all its scenarios on right hand side

Issue here is that i am not sure where to implement createtest() method in the framework and how to log feature name dynamically.

1. With com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter it
   dynamically captures feature file name automatically and it works
   fine for me but this has limited methods like Reporter.addStepLog("String")
2. Hence I want to achieve this with com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/html/ExtentReport.html
   plugin since i want to use methods like createnode() to create node under each scenarios, log info etc so that i can attach screenshot at every node

I did try using ItestListeners, hooks etc but was not able to find solution.

please advise.

Please see notes on the picture to understand my requirement [Issue with Vimalsevan plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zceL.png)

[Issue with com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter plugin with creatTest() method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybGB8.png)

Comment: You have not specified your ExtentReports and Cucumber versions.

Comment: @foursyth - below are dependencies

<dependency>
<groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
<version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
 
<dependency>
<groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
<artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
<version>3.0.7</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
<dependency>
<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
<version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I am looking for logging capabilities, creating nodes(within ONE "Given" step) and log test data used and attached screenshots to that specific node as needed.